# How to access the URI of the previous page in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to find out on the current page of my WP7 app which page the user came from?

I'm looking for the equivalent of a http referer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reference this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation(v=VS.92).aspx
and have a look at BackStack property of the NavigationService, the drawback though is if you were previously developing on WP7.0 then the BackStack property isn't available.  hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
PhoneApplicationFrame frame = (PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual;    
if (frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                string pageUri = String.Empty;
                foreach (var item in frame.BackStack)
                {
                    pageUri = item.Source.ToString();
                }
            }
```

After executing this code, `pageUri` should be holding the Uri of the last page.