# How to retrieve Uri of page we are returning from

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an application that can fire several pages depending on the button I press.

When returning to the main page, is there a way to determine which page it is coming from?

I looked into onNavigatedTo, onNavigatingFrom or onNavigatedFrom, when coming back from a page, only onNavigatedTo is called.

I'm targeting WP7 7.0, I see that in 7.1 there's now a BackStack property but it isn't available in 7.0.

I find it quite amazing on how difficult it is to know such important information, at the end of the day, all I'm looking for is being able to pass parameters back from a page to the original caller

(I did read [How to access the URI of the previous page in Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856199/how-to-access-the-uri-of-the-previous-page-in-windows-phone-7), but that answer isn't suitable using 7.0)

Comment: Why the bloody hell are you targeting 7.0 ? All phones been updated with Mango.

Comment: @Claus There are some devices/carriers which are still "in testing" for the mango update. And not everyone who has it available to them has updated yet. If trying to amke an app which is available to everyone then targetting 7.0 is still, for now, necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have need to do this as well but I don't think this is provided 'out of the box'. You might have to write you own way of doing it. You could save the current page into isolated storage and update it each time you leave a page.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... WP7 is becoming more and more a pain in the arse to do anything that should normally be trivial. You would have thought MS has experience on what methods are required for writing common apps

Comment: I agree, hopefully it will get better as it matures. I do like the phone. Can you mark my post as 'answer' if it was helpful. Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to send the page as a querystring, for example:

```
target.xaml?source=sourcepage
```

Comment: But doing so means you accumulate pages in the navigation stack , and never pop the value...